# How to nest Job Streams in IBM Workload scheduler?

Tags: workload-scheduler

I have a business requirement where I need to create a Job Stream to aggregate a few other Job Streams.

My current business process contains over 6 streams that runs one after another with the FOLLOWs keyword. However I need to create a on demand SCHEDULE to execute all 6 streams in just one submission, that can be executed on demand at any time.

How can I achieve that? I do NOT want to create 1 Big Stream and copy and paste all the jobs there. Instead I'd love to just reference all job streams that I need in just one Job Stream so I could execute it in 1 submission only.

I couldn't find any ways to nest job Streams. I definitely appreciate you help on this.

Example on what I need:

---

```
SCHEDULE W1#JOB_STREAM_1
ON RUNCYCLE EXAMPLE "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1"
:
  W1#JOB_A
END

SCHEDULE W1#JOB_STREAM_2
ON RUNCYCLE EXAMPLE "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1"
FOLLLOWS W1#JOB_STREAM_1
:
  W1#JOB_B
END

# I need this Stream to be executed on Demand so I don't have to manually submit JOB_STREAM_1 and JOB_STREAM_2 when they ask me to execute them OUTSIDE of the scheduled time.
SCHEDULE W1#STREAM_AGGREGATION
ON REQUEST
:
  W1#JOB_STREAM_1

  W1#JOB_STREAM_2
END
```

I've checked everywhere in IBM documentation and couldn't find any reference on nested Job Streams

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly nesting, although in your aggregation job stream you can use the Job Stream Submission jobs to submit the other 2 job streams.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/workload-automation/10.2.0?topic=capabilities-job-stream-submission-jobs